# How to decompress websocket answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, compression

I tried to make human-readable  websocket response. 
I get this:

```
b'\x92\xaa"\x00\xb1\x997\r\xd4\x86D\x02\xbe\xf5\xc4\x00!\x1c]\x16\xdcE\xdf\x04xY\xa4\x00I\n!\x1e\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xfc\xe1\xe7\x00\xb9$\x1c\x14d\xd9(\x00\x14\xcd\x06\x03q\xdah \x13\x99\x16\x03\x8fr\x11\x07\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07eN\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xf9A\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x070H\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x06\x9a\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x9a\x8d\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07.H\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x04\x9a\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x98\x8d\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xd1\x93\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xcd\x93\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07;\xa0\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07c\x87\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xad\x85\xdf\x00)\x1e\x1d\x13\x92\xbc\x12\x03iS\xe7\x00y=O\x1d\x0e,\xbc\t\xfe\xa1#\x00\xb1eU\x0b\x1f\x0bu\x07\xeb\xab-\x00\xd1\xcf\x8b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x89\x07\x00\x89\xab=\x0b\xd4\x86D\x02g\xa4/\x00i\xcd5 \x99\xeaF\x07)=^\x00\xd1<\xf0\x1b\xdf\x16O\x03\x9eg\xe2\x00\t\xc8g\x0b\xd4\x86D\x02?\x90[\x00a_\x85\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb5\x9br\x00\xe1|[\x0f7\xc4w\x07-\x8d4\x00\t]9\x17\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xd6\xd9\xaa\x00\xe96A\n\xa4\n\xe2\x05r\x06+\x00\x81\xb1N\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\xf0\x07\x00\xe1\xa1Y\x07,\x1a,\x0b\r\xfdo\x00\x19>\xd8\x1d\xd4\x86D\x02k\xa8/\x00\xf1[\xec\x1f,\x1a,\x0b\x8b\xdf\xab\x00\xd9\xec\xdd\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd1\x98\x02\x00\xf9DC\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcay\x02\x00\x11a\'\x0e\xfd([\x01\xf2\xf0\xd2\x00A\x9c\x8d\x12b\xb6\xc7\x04\x15,*\x00Q\xbc<\x1eY3\x07\x04\xd3\x8fX\x00\x01\xaaC\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf7\xdc\x03\x00iNb\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xee.\x00q\xdah \x13\x99\x16\x03\xde\xfd\x9d\x00Q\xc3f\x11z\x9a\xa4\x08\xa6M\xd7\x00\xb9\x1d\x13\x15\x1c\xa2\xe3\x03\x01\xcfm\x00\xf9\xb17\x1c\xdb\xe7\xa2\n\xe2y\xa3\x00\xe9\xb3\x9c\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xf6\x97\x00)\x86\x17\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x0e\x08\x00\xf1\xb3$\x14\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xf9\x1a\xbb\x00!\xcd\x99\r\xa4\n\xe2\x05(\xc3(\x00)\x9e\x7f\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\x82S\x00\xa1\xf2\xdd\x0bY3\x07\x04\x1cH7\x00\x89\xd5\xcf\x15\xd6;\xaf\x01'
```

How to decompress it?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = b'\x92\xaa"\x00\xb1\x997\r\xd4\x86D\x02\xbe\xf5\xc4\x00!\x1c]\x16\xdcE\xdf\x04xY\xa4\x00I\n!\x1e\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xfc\xe1\xe7\x00\xb9$\x1c\x14d\xd9(\x00\x14\xcd\x06\x03q\xdah \x13\x99\x16\x03\x8fr\x11\x07\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07eN\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xf9A\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x070H\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x06\x9a\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x9a\x8d\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07.H\x92\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x04\x9a\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\x98\x8d\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xd1\x93\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xcd\x93\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07;\xa0\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07c\x87\x88\x01\x81T\xd8\x08\x99\xeaF\x07\xad\x85\xdf\x00)\x1e\x1d\x13\x92\xbc\x12\x03iS\xe7\x00y=O\x1d\x0e,\xbc\t\xfe\xa1#\x00\xb1eU\x0b\x1f\x0bu\x07\xeb\xab-\x00\xd1\xcf\x8b\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x89\x07\x00\x89\xab=\x0b\xd4\x86D\x02g\xa4/\x00i\xcd5 \x99\xeaF\x07)=^\x00\xd1<\xf0\x1b\xdf\x16O\x03\x9eg\xe2\x00\t\xc8g\x0b\xd4\x86D\x02?\x90[\x00a_\x85\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb5\x9br\x00\xe1|[\x0f7\xc4w\x07-\x8d4\x00\t]9\x17\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xd6\xd9\xaa\x00\xe96A\n\xa4\n\xe2\x05r\x06+\x00\x81\xb1N\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb6\xf0\x07\x00\xe1\xa1Y\x07,\x1a,\x0b\r\xfdo\x00\x19>\xd8\x1d\xd4\x86D\x02k\xa8/\x00\xf1[\xec\x1f,\x1a,\x0b\x8b\xdf\xab\x00\xd9\xec\xdd\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd1\x98\x02\x00\xf9DC\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcay\x02\x00\x11a\'\x0e\xfd([\x01\xf2\xf0\xd2\x00A\x9c\x8d\x12b\xb6\xc7\x04\x15,*\x00Q\xbc<\x1eY3\x07\x04\xd3\x8fX\x00\x01\xaaC\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf7\xdc\x03\x00iNb\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xee.\x00q\xdah \x13\x99\x16\x03\xde\xfd\x9d\x00Q\xc3f\x11z\x9a\xa4\x08\xa6M\xd7\x00\xb9\x1d\x13\x15\x1c\xa2\xe3\x03\x01\xcfm\x00\xf9\xb17\x1c\xdb\xe7\xa2\n\xe2y\xa3\x00\xe9\xb3\x9c\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xf6\x97\x00)\x86\x17\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00O\x0e\x08\x00\xf1\xb3$\x14\xa4\n\xe2\x05\xf9\x1a\xbb\x00!\xcd\x99\r\xa4\n\xe2\x05(\xc3(\x00)\x9e\x7f\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1\x82S\x00\xa1\xf2\xdd\x0bY3\x07\x04\x1cH7\x00\x89\xd5\xcf\x15\xd6;\xaf\x01'

'.'.join(str(ord(c)) for c in a)
```

Comment: It isn't work. TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found.
I replaced ord with chr, but it isn't work too.